# How do I set a Timer that executes my code every 60sec?

Tags: c#, timer

I am working in Visual Studio 2017 in C# WinForms- The project is based on a conversion from VB6 to C#. What it does right now is that I press a GetQue-button which gather a key that resembles a document, thereafter that document is exported through mail to another mail.

Now for the last point I need to create a Timer where it executes all of this code every 60sec.
I really appreciate all types solutions and I really do not know a lot about timers, but I would really like some simple explanation as well.

**Note** that I have only used a timer in an simple console app once.

Comment: The problem with timed processes/tasks is getting sure they do happen and that they do they work as intended. What if the executions takes 65 seconds? Does it need to be executed regardless of the winforms app being running? The Timer class is the same regardless being called from a Console or a Winforms application, there are also many scheduler API's (comes to mind quartz.net), or you could create a normal console exe and use Windows Scheduled Tasks. Or create your own scheduler creating a windows service with a timer... Depends on what are your exact requirements

Comment: Almost all of the documentation for the various timer classes in .NET has examples and helps you select which one might be most appropriate for your use case. Have you looked at those?

Comment: @Cleptus As you mentioned  "What if the executions takes 65 seconds?", I want it to only execute during that 60 sec interval, the earlier VB6 code is executed during that interval so I just want to make it the same. But I also don´t want 2 processes active at the same time. Simply I want the code executed every 60 sec, but not if an process is already active.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Do you have a link?

Comment: use `System.Timer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this code below, the timer will execute the button click which starts the process and it is done within a 60sec interval.

```
private void StartTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (bRunning == false)
            {

                bRunning = true;
                BtnGetQue_Click(sender, e);
                bRunning = false;

            }

        }
```